# IE7 not reading CSS and JS bundles

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-7, minify

I'm facing a weird behavior of IE7.

In my application I have a dozens of JSs and CSSs files. Due to the number of requests to load each page, I decided to pack all them together in just two files, a bundle with all the CSS files (css_pack.css) and another one with all the JS files (js_pack.js).

Everything goes fine with FF, Chrome, IE8. The problem is on displaying my application on IE7. In IE7 it seems that the packs (both css and js) are not being read. That is, my application is entirely out of formating and lost a lot of dynamic js bahavior (jquery).

After a lot of tests I tried to remove the bundles and point each file separately. Now, the things come back to work in IE7, along with my performance issue...

Well, is this familiar to anyone? Why only IE7 don't like my bundles?

**UPDATE:**

This is a piece of my head section:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/blueprint/screen-nopack.css"/>" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/blueprint/print-nopack.css"/>" type="text/css" media="print">
<!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/blueprint/ie-nopack.css"/>" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/css_pack.css"/>" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
<!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/11-jqtransform.css"/>" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/js/js_pack.js"/>"></script>
<!--[if IE]> <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/js/excanvas-nopack.js"/>"></script> <![endif]-->
</head>
```

The file pointed by the line...

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/11-jqtransform.css"/>" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->
```

... makes part of the css bundle (css_pack.css). However, it's content is only read by IE when it's distinct line is added to the head...

**UPDATE2**

This is the HTML code generated by the processing of the previous JSP and received by IE7:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/GestorAMPB/css/blueprint/screen-nopack.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/GestorAMPB/css/blueprint/print-nopack.css" type="text/css" media="print">
<!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="/GestorAMPB/css/blueprint/ie-nopack.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/GestorAMPB/css/css_pack.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
<!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="/GestorAMPB/css/11-jqtransform.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/GestorAMPB/js/js_pack.js"></script>
<!--[if IE]> <script type="text/javascript" src="/GestorAMPB/js/excanvas-nopack.js"></script> <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Comment: Can you post some code? Are you using fully closed `<script></script>` constructs or are you using self-closing `<script />` tags?

Comment: Yeah, we need to see some code. What do the bundles look like?

Comment: Hi Joel and Pekka, a piece of my head section in the first update:

Comment: That's not valid HTML, I assume you posted some server side-processed code. Can you post the HTML as it's sent to the browser?

Comment: Sorry Marcel, that was the content of my jsp. In the second update is the result of the processing of the JSP.

Answer (score 2):

what method do you use to pack these resources? i assume you must cat them together first, this is where some problems can come in for you.

in the case of js files make sure they each have a newline at the end of the file and last line ends with ;

in the case of css files, do you have any css that runs js code? ive seen issues with this when its catted together.

finally, have you tried ie debugging tools to see how much of the js/css is loaded? usually there is an problem where some percent of the file loads while the rest does not, find out where that break is and look in the catted file output

Comment: Hi mkoryak, you are right. I'm just appending each file read by my script at the end of a new file. None of my css run js code and, unfortunately, the debug tools don't say anything useful to me. There is no explicit errors or warnings. The only problem is that they don't "see" the definitons of my css classes when I just fetch the css pack, but they do so when I import the css one by one...

Comment: can you paste in what your js and/or css looks like once its all appended together?

Comment: sorry, cant see anything that jumps out.. try this: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input run that and copy down "valid css information" at the bottom and use that as your css file in ie7, if it likes it, you can work your way back toward what you used to have

Comment: I tried the CSS suggested by jigsaw. Well, things are a bit better but there are still a lot of problems. Thanks anyway mkoryak and everyone, but now the solution points to convince my client of using chrome and firefox. It's easier to develop to these guys and the results have a better appearance with css3. As it is an intranet application, I think it's quite reasonable...